# qcombobox do not display current text when choose item

Tags: qt, qt5, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox connect to model and display list of text item from model, but when I choose one of its item, QComboBox display item text, but when I click on other widget (QComboBox lost focus), current text become empty

```
cboProfiles->setModel(QComboBoxModel);
cboProfiles->setModelColumn(0);
cboProfiles->setEditable(true);
```

follow is my model QComboBoxModel.h

```
#ifndef QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H
#define QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H

#include <QModelIndex>


class QComboBoxModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    QComboBoxModel(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    void populate(const QList<QPair<int,QString>> &values);
    void append(int index, QString value);

private:
    QList<QPair<int,QString>> values;
};

#endif // QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H
```

here is QComboBoxModel.cpp

```
#include "qcomboboxmodel.h"

#include <QModelIndex>

QComboBoxModel::QComboBoxModel(QObject *parent)
    :QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

int QComboBoxModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return values.count();
}


QVariant QComboBoxModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const
{        

    QVariant value;

        switch ( role )
        {
            case Qt::DisplayRole: //string
            {
                value = this->values.value(index.row()).second;
            }
            break;

            case Qt::UserRole: //data
            {
            value = this->values.value(index.row()).first;
            }
            break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    return value;
}

void QComboBoxModel::populate(const QList<QPair<int,QString>> &values)
{
    this->values = values;
}

void QComboBoxModel::append(int index, QString value)
{
    int newRow = this->values.count();

    this->beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), newRow, newRow);

    values.append(QPair<int, QString>(index, value));

    endInsertRows();
}
```

here is my use code:

```
QComboBox* combobox = new QComboBox;
    QList<QPair<int, QString>> values;
    values.append(QPair<int, QString>(-1, "Select item"));
    values.append(QPair<int, QString>(10, "item1(0)"));
    values.append(QPair<int, QString>(11, "item1(1)"));
    values.append(QPair<int, QString>(21, "item1(2)"));
    values.append(QPair<int, QString>(32, "item1(3)"));
    values.append(QPair<int, QString>(44, "item1(4)"));
    QComboBoxModel *model = new QComboBoxModel();
    model->populate(values);
    combobox->setModel(model);
    combobox->setEditable(true);
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: i've edited my post to add some code